# Else not working in setOnClickListener KOTLIN

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I am a beginner at Android Studio and KOTLIN. Please check out my problem.

Code:

```
class getOTP : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_otp)
    
        val inputCode1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputCode1).text.toString()
        val inputCode2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputCode2).text.toString()
        val inputCode3 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputCode3).text.toString()
        val inputCode4 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputCode4).text.toString()
    
        val verifyOTPButtonOne = findViewById<Button>(R.id.verifyOTPButtonOne)
        verifyOTPButtonOne.setOnClickListener {
            if(inputCode1 == "" || inputCode2 == "" || inputCode3 == "" || inputCode4 == ""){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Please Enter Correct OTP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
             }
             else {
                 val intent = Intent(this, VerifySuccess::class.java)
                     startActivity(intent)
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM: Here, after inputting all 4 text fields the toast is still appearing and Activity is not starting.**

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the value of the text fields only once, at the moment you call `.toString()` on them. So the `if` in the `onClickListener` only checks the initial values of the text fields.

You would have to call `.toString()` *inside* the listener for it to react appropriately, or you could just call `isEmpty()` directly on the `Editable` since it implements `CharSequence`:

```kotlin
class getOTP : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_otp)
    
        val inputCode1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputCode1)
        val inputCode2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputCode2)
        val inputCode3 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputCode3)
        val inputCode4 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.inputCode4)
    
        val verifyOTPButtonOne = findViewById<Button>(R.id.verifyOTPButtonOne)
        verifyOTPButtonOne.setOnClickListener {
            if(inputCode1.text.isEmpty() || inputCode2.text.isEmpty() || inputCode3.text.isEmpty() || inputCode4.text.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Please Enter Correct OTP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                val intent = Intent(this, VerifySuccess::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```